# Networking issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, xubuntu, vpn, 22.04

I have upgraded my ubuntu machine from 20.04 to 22.04 but has landed into lot of issues.

Only google surfing works, if I click on any link it doesn't work. My overall system has slowed down. Vpn doesn't work.

**Solutions tried:**

1. I have upgraded kernel to 5.18.0 but no luck
2. Also tried some of the options suggested in some articles but nothing works like changing wifi power from 3 to 2 etc.
3. Also no hardware or software is blocked for wifi
4. Added screenshot of curl after network issues starts and it shows some tls related issue

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the responses of these commands: `ip addr` `ip route` `ip neigh` `ping 8.8.8.8` `dig google.com` `ping 1.1.1.1` `dig google.com @1.1.1.1`

Comment: Added screenshots to description itself. Fortunately it was working and I was able to add screenshots, After sometime it will stop working

Comment: Now I connected to VPN it worked for 5 mins and again same situation nothing works. Also disconnected vpn and nothing works except google surfing

Comment: It seems that the basic network connection is fine, but the SSL layer does not work. Please try two more tests in a state where the defect is manifested. 1) Open some unencrypted page http://www.httpvshttps.com/  2) Check the system clock for an incorrect time - year, time zone, etc. `date` `date -u`

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the various solutions found, I noticed that the update changed the name of the board from enp2s0 to enp0s3. Once the name in the configuration file was corrected, everything started working again.